# client section not aligned in html

Tags: html, css

I am very new to html css and I have this problem:

I want to create a partner section with 5 pictures. At the moment it looks likes this: [howitisnow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5rML.png). It is not aligned horizontal in one line and the pictures got different sizes.

Actually I want that my client section looks like this:
[howtolook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tzPg.png).

Can someone help me with this?

Here is my html code:

```
<section class="page-section" id="services">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-8 text-center">
                <h2 class="title font-bold mt-0">Client</h2>
                <hr class="divider my-4">
                <p class="subtitle mb-5">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem alias voluptates id harum expedita doloremque non explicabo cum inventore possimus!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <section class="py-5">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="stylesheets/post.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="stylesheets/auto.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="stylesheets/dts.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="stylesheets/mobiliar.png" alt="">


         </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="stylesheets/pf.JPG" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a live demo using codepen.io or jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Here is the my codepen project: [link](https://codepen.io/bzcode/pen/MWaQwyz). @SMAKSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve such a thing all you need to do is just give an `offset-md-1` to your first element in inner section div, so the result should be something like this:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 offset-md-1">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** This will just make them appear in 5 columns in large screens.

Here is the working demo: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/smalikss/pen/xxwYGeO)

Comment: @user11012430 Cool, so please don't forget to mark it as an answer to help other peeps in the community to find their answer if they facing the same issue. :D If you don't know how to do it [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) might help.